# Display String array with struts 2 in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, pre

I want to display string array on jsp. below is the code I have written :

```
<s:iterator value="ccActivityOperationVO.output" var="Output">
    <s:property value="#Output"/><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

With this code i am able to print string array, but I am losing formatting like spaces before and after text is no more.
Note: I have not used any kind of trimming.

Comment: The white space before and after the value is probably there, just not shown by the browser. Check the page source (in your browser) to confirm this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `<pre>` tag around the value. It preserves white space.

```
<s:iterator value="ccActivityOperationVO.output" var="Output">
    <pre><s:property value="#Output"/></pre><br/>
</s:iterator>
```

Add following style in the HTML head

```
<style type='text/css'> pre {display: inline;} </style>
```

Comment: pre causes additional line breaks :(